# CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB for xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, xhtml

I'm trying to make a custom tag in jsf, here is my code:
WEB-INF/tag/test.xhtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" default="#000000" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <input jsf:id="#{cc.id}" name="#{cc.id}" jsf:value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                type="color" />
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

the problem is that eclipse doesn't recognize 
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
it give me a warning says:

```
    NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

so what is the problem.
Note: all the other Namespaces work fine unless this one

Answer (score 1):

This is an Eclipse quirk. Try one of the following things:

Close/reopen project.

Rightclick project > Validate.

Project > Clean... and clean selected project.

Restart Eclipse.

Comment: A fat -1 for [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077).

Comment: how come it is plagiarism , do you know the original source please mention that also

Comment: @Panther: because those were my words. Check the abovelinked duplicate question for the source. By the way, unthoughtful sympathy upvotes is damaging for the quality of Stack Overflow. Please don't do that while awaiting the response.

Comment: @BalusC You should have given link explaining where you have posted same. i saw this answer in review queque so was not aware about duplicate question. Anyways this question it self will be deleted.

Comment: @Panther: A good reviewer reviews beyond the context before taking actions. Don't be ashamed, there are even moderators who are doing it wrong here.

Comment: @BalusC Sure will take care. Thanks for suggestion.